# Altering all urls to include extra information

Tags: 7, routes

What hooks are available for altering the urls? For example, there are language modules that, when enabled, provide urls such as `/en/node/1` rather than leaving it as `/node/1`.

I want to have something similar in the url, that I can have access to without having other functionality compromised.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're looking for a way to modify a link URL as it is being written? I looked into this recently and was surprised at how much hunting was required.

I went with [`hook_url_outbound_alter( &$path, &$options, $original_path )`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7), which allows you to alter link URLs that are being written by the Drupal URL system.

There's also [`hook_url_inbound_alter( &$path, $original_path, $path_language )`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7), which might be better as it includes the path's specific langauge - it depends on where you want the alteration to take place. I personally find `hook_url_outbound_alter()` reliable and simple to work with - it changes all appropriate URLs as they are written, and using $options you can reliably add and edit query strings (...?query=string&foo=bar) and hash frangments (...#someId).

Modify $path and it'll update the actual path that gets written into the URL href. Of course, this runs on all links, so you'll want to start by checking that it's a link you want to modify.

It's executed before aliasing, so it'll be based on the Drupal defaults. To give two very simplistic examples, if you want to modify only taxonomy paths:

```
function some_module_url_outbound_alter( &$path, &$options, $original_path ) {
  if(strpos($original_path, 'taxonomy/term') === 0) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

And/or if you only want it to run on particular pages, e.g. node edit pages:

```
function some_module_url_outbound_alter( &$path, &$options, $original_path ) {
  $current_path = explode("/", current_path() );
  if (count($current_path) >= 3 && $current_path[0] == "node" && $current_path[2] == "edit") {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```